# Currency Symbol issue in iPhone and iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to show Turkey Symbol in my iPhone application. In iOS 7.0 is it working find but in iOS 6.0 its coming as square box. 
Any idea would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a NSString value of   @"\u20BA"  for your symbol?

Comment: Cris:Thanks for your reply. I have tried the same but it is not showing me the actual value. It is showing me the same square box. I tried this by setting the text value of a UILabel. When I am trying to print that UIlabel in console its showing me proper text with other UILabel details.